# Deducing std::string from const char* or char* when creating a std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple, type-deduction

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to deducing a `std::string` from a `const char*` when making a tuple.
That would be possible with my own tuple implementation but I'm wondering if it is possible with `std::tuple`

For example in the code below `storage_` will have the type of :

`std::tuple<int, int, const char*>`

`std::tuple<const char*, char*>`

I would like to get :

`std::tuple<int, int, std::string>`

`std::tuple<std::string, std::string>`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
template<typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    foo(T storage) : storage_(std::move(storage)) {}
private:
    T storage_;
};

int main()
{
    char* s2 = strdup("123");

    foo f { std::make_tuple(12,123,"1234") };

    foo f2 { std::make_tuple("321", s2) };

    free(s2);
    // still want to keep s2 stored in f2
}
```

I know I can write `std::tuple<int,std::string> t1 = std::make_tuple(123,"12");` but that doesn't solve my problem as I want to have any number of arguments passed in any order

**Solution:** https://wandbox.org/permlink/MsUxZ18SYD1K2ujv

Comment: Are you fine with adding a trailing "s"? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: No I would like to use the tuple as storage space, so I basically want to store copies of the const char* strings. For example instead of passing a string literal it could be passing a s.c_str(); I updated the code in the question so it is more clear

Comment: @Ody: The vast majority of the time, the non-literal cases can be made to be strings in the first place (e.g. `std::getline` to populate a `std::string` instead of `istream.getline` to populate a `char*`), so the trailing `s` approach to string literals closes most of the remaining gap. In the remaining cases not covered, you're likely working with C APIs, and being explicit about the conversion to `std::string` is the way to go. I'm fairly sure `std::tuple` won't support this out of the box; you'd have to write your own wrapper.

Comment: @Ody: "*No I would like to use the tuple as storage space, so I basically want to store copies of the `const char*` strings.*" That is exactly what the `s` literal would do. It will create a `std::string`, which copies the string literal into itself, and that would be what gets stored in the `tuple`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: They meant that some of these won't be literals, so the suffix doesn't help them in those cases (that said, it's a better solution in the cases it applies, since the `s` prefix automatically invokes the pre-sized constructor using the compile-time known length,  instead of having to scan for a `NUL` terminator at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of wether this is something you should be doing or not, the question can still be answered as asked:

I don't think  you'll be able to pull this off without providing your own `make_tuple`.

Thankfully, a lot of the heavy lifting can still be done by `std::make_tuple()`. All you have to do, really, is explicitely specify the template arguments, instead of letting them be deduced:

```
template<typename T>
struct Promoted {
    using type = T;
};

template<>
struct Promoted<const char *> {
    using type = std::string;
};

template<typename T>
using Promoted_t = typename Promoted<T>::type;

template<typename... ArgsT>
auto make_my_tuple(ArgsT&&... args) {
    return std::make_tuple<Promoted_t<std::decay_t<ArgsT>>...>(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** The code I posted is not meant to be a complete solution. It's a guideline on how I would tackle the issue. There are probably some edge cases not being covered here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've added a wandbox example using your solution